# Heating and cooling based on ordinary differential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

> The room temperature in your office is $70 \,°\rm F$. Experience has taught you that the temperature of a cup of coffee will drop from $120 \,°\rm F$ to $100 \,°\rm F$ in $10$ minutes. What should be the temperature of your cup of coffee if you want it to take $20$ minutes before it drops to $100  \,°\rm F$?

Comment: i even dont know how to start

Comment: You could start by producing an actual ODE. I suppose you're talking about "Newton cooling" (or something like that), which is described by a 1st order ODE.

Answer (score 0):

The Newton cooling law establishes

$$
T(t) = T_s + (T_i - T_s) e^{-K t}
$$

where

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
T_s &=& \mbox{surrounding temperature}\\
T_i &=& \mbox{initial temperature}\\
K &=& \mbox{cooling constant}\\
t &=& \mbox{time}
\end{array}
$$

so we have

$$
100^{\circ} = 70^{\circ}+\left(120^{\circ}-70^{\circ}\right)e^{-10K}\Rightarrow K
$$

after computing $K$ we have

$$
100^{\circ} = \left(T_i-70^{\circ}\right)e^{-20 K}
$$

and then we can compute $T_i$